# import / opening existing Codenameone project from Netbeans / Eclipse to IntelliJ does not work

Tags: codenameone

Finally, I thought of moving my project from Eclipse to IDE to IntelliJ. So, I carried out the following steps:
1. Installed Codenameone plugin in IntelliJ.
2. Import existing project to IntelliJ. Now I project structure is as shown in the figure.
[image]

Here, CodenameOne-Project is the main project including source folders images and all. The common and barcode-common consists of java classes required for main project(i.e.CodenameOne-Project). So, I am able to import CodenameOne-Project in IntelliJ, and if I add other folder as module by adding dependency and all, it dont look like CodenameOne project anymore. I cant properly import complete project. Any help on this would be very helpful. Thanks
P.S:  I want to maintain same project structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't support importing projects between IDE's as our project structure is IDE agnostic. The IDE won't recognize that and would fail. The right thing to do is create a new project with the same package name/main class name as your existing project then copy your `src` & `res` directories on top of the new project and copy `codenameone_settings.properties` on top of the new project file.